# How to copy downloaded file to publish directory with msbuild?

Tags: msbuild

I'd like to download and copy files to the publish directory with MSBuild. I've tried the following which seems pretty obvious:

```xml
  <Target Name="DownloadContentFiles" BeforeTargets="BeforePublish">
    <DownloadFile SourceUrl="$(LatestValidatorUrl)" DestinationFolder="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)">
      <Output TaskParameter="DownloadedFile" ItemName="Content" />
    </DownloadFile>
  </Target>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="org.hl7.fhir.validator.jar" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

However `CopyToPublishDirectory` is running *before* `BeforeTargets="BeforePublish"` runs, so it fails to find the file.

I've tried many other variations as well, but nothing is working.

How can I download a file and copy it to the publish directory before the `Publish` step runs?